# Raster and Geometry ST_Intersects slows when add buffer in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table containing rasters for the whole of the UK, the below query is very fast (0.1 seconds) and gets all of the rasters that are intersected by the line between a start point and an end point:

```
SELECT ST_UNION(rast) INTO elevationdata
FROM uk_rasters e
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, ST_Makeline(CAST(startloc AS GEOMETRY), CAST(endloc AS GEOMETRY)));
```

I want to do the same, but with a buffer around the line, like so:

```
SELECT ST_UNION(rast) INTO elevationdata
FROM uk_rasters e
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, ST_Buffer(ST_Makeline(CAST(startloc AS GEOMETRY), CAST(endloc AS GEOMETRY)), 75));
```

This was still running after 4 minutes. I assume the buffer is somehow stopping ST_Intersects from using the Index on the table. I saw mentions of ST_DWithin, but I don't see a version that takes a raster and a geometry.

Is there another approach I should be using here?

Comment: Try rewritting your query like this: `SELECT ST_UNION(rast) INTO elevationdata
FROM uk_rasters e, (SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Makeline(CAST(startloc AS GEOMETRY), CAST(endloc AS GEOMETRY)), 75) as geom) AS buff
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, buff.geom );` It isn't testing, so I might have a couple of parenthesis in wrong place, but the general idea is that spatial indices work better when you arrange it this way, rather than having a sub-query inside ST_Intersects with an operation like Buffer

Comment: Still taking an age and not coming back after 4 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible improvement would be to create the line buffer once, and re-use that for each raster. As currently you're recreating the buffer for each raster.

```
WITH linebuffer AS (
SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Makeline(CAST(startloc AS GEOMETRY), CAST(endloc AS GEOMETRY)), 75) AS linebuffer_geom
)
SELECT ST_UNION(rast) INTO elevationdata
FROM uk_rasters, linebuffer
WHERE rast && linebuff_geom
AND ST_INTERSECTS(rast, linebuff_geom)
```

**EDIT**

Checking the unit for the projection you're using may help, 75 metres & 75 decimal degrees are worlds apart :).

Comment: Thanks Andy, I didn't realise that it would create it every time, sadly this did not solve the slow down though.

Comment: I've just edited my answer to use a bounding box lookup, which should use the index on the rasters. [PostGIS &&](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Geometry_Overlap.html), try that.

Comment: Sadly still not coming back, is there any further analysis I can do within my function that would help see what is going on? I checked the original query without the st_buffer and its still 0.1 seconds, so indexing is there and good.

Comment: Just out of interest, are your rasters projected in EPSG:27700?

Comment: No, I used ST_Transform with alignto to create a new table of 4326 aligned rasters that I then created a new index on.

Comment: The function goes on to sample points by using ST_VALUE on the elevationdata we union together. All very fast, but I'm getting a number of z=0's and wondered if it was due to elevationdata not quite being 'wide' enough. So the thought process was to add a buffer around the line im sampling on to grab a few more rasters in the union. Then I hit the speed issue with the union/intersects (I've checked its definitely this part and not the latter part of the function)

Comment: You might not be buffering your line by 75 metres then, I think the unit for EPSG:4326 is decimal degrees.

Comment: That would cause issues! Yes, using 0.0012 as a quick guess at 75m in the UK gets the speed back. Do you want to add that to your answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: That'd be one big buffer, answer edited.